# just rooted oneplus CM12.1, synapse opens but is completely black

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, oneplus-one

I have the latest nightly for CM12 on my oneplus1. I also have the latest AK kernel. 
I wanted to install synapse so I rooted my phone with supersu.  Everything seems to go well, but when I open synapse its completely black. There not even the message that I " need to be root".

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know the reason for blackout but you can consider [Kernel Adiutor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor) as a replacement for Synapse. Also, remove the AK kernel, flash the CM12.1 kernel and see how Synapse behaves. In some custom ROMs I noticed the similar blackout for some apps and they took very long time to ask for root access. At some point, I didn't even get to see the dialog for root permissions because it happened in the background. I later checked my SuperSu app and there I saw the entry for the app.